# Getting TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I am solving an exercise and I got this error:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
I tried reading some explanations but didn't get where I am wrong in my code

```
def reverse(num):
    r=0
    while(num!=0):
        r=(r*10)+(num%10)
        num //= 10
    return r

num=input("Enter a number: ")
n=reverse(num)
numOdd=[]
numEven=[]
c=1
while(n!=0):
    if (c%2==0):
        numEven.append(n%10)
    else:
        numOdd.append(n%10)
    n//= 10
    c += 1
sortedEven=True
sortedOdd=True
for i in range(len(numOdd)-1):
    if(numOdd[i]>numOdd[i+1]):
        sortedOdd=False
for i in range(len(numEven)-1):
    if(numEven[i]<numEven[i+1]):
        sortedEven=False

if(sortedOdd==True and sortedEven==True):
    print ("True")
else:
    print ("False")
```

Comment: In `num=input("Enter a number: ")`, `num` will be a _string_, so you can't treat it as a number

Comment: So what do I do to make my code work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:**
`input` returns a string, so `num` in `num=input("Enter a number: ")` is a string, not a number. `reverse` expects its argument to be a number, but gets a string, so this "messes things up" (the actual cause is explained below). To fix that, convert `num` to an integer:

```
num=int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

---

Actually, this is a tricky one.

1. Here: `num=input("Enter a number: ")` `input` returns a *string*, so `num` is a string
2. In `reverse`, here: `r=(r*10)+(num%10)` `num % 10` is basically the same as `"whatever string" % 10`, where the `%` will do [string formatting](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#1-old-style-string-formatting-operator) (!!), *not* compute the modulus of a number.
3. For a string to be suitable as the first argument of the string formatting operator (`%`), it must have at least one [conversion specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) - basically, it must contain a percent sign (`%`), like this: `"whatever %s"`
4. These conversion specifiers are mapped one-to-one to the elements of the second argument of `%`: if you have 1 such specifier in your string, there must be one argument supplied to `%` that's not an empty tuple (`()`), and vice versa
5. Your number surely doesn't contain a conversion specifier, yet `%` got a second argument `10`. So that 10, as the error message says, cannot be "converted during string formatting" because no formatting specifier is associated with it

Okay, what is any of that?! Basically, your code attempts to do math on a *string*, and it so happens that the `%` operator makes sense for both strings and numbers, yet it has different meanings in these cases.

Comment: Wow!! thank you for the most detailed answer I've got :)
Thank you so so much